# where can I get SRVResolver sample code?

Tags: ios, networking, bluetooth

I'm trying to learn how to do bluetooth streaming on the iOS. In the sample code mentioned in [Technical Q&A QA1753](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1753/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011315) there is a reference to another sample code called SRVResolver:

> If you want the callbacks to run on a specific run loop, you can use DNSServiceRefSockFD to get the DNS-SD socket, wrap that in a CFSocket, and then      schedule the CFSocket on the run loop.  The SRVResolver sample code shows an example of this.
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SRVResolver/

However that link no longer exists on the apple dev site.. and I couldn't find an example of it any where else on the web.. can anyone direct me to where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SRVResolver` does not seem to exist in OS X 10.8 docset. It can be found in 10.6 and 10.7 docsets.

In 10.8, there's the `DNSSDObjects` example, which looks similar, but I didn't look exactly at what it does. QA1753 was updated to refer to this new sample.

Googling for `SRVResolver filetype:m` did not produce any results, but older docsets *should* still be available for download from within Xcode's Preferences.